# MD711B, MD711LLA... How do I figure out which version is newer?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am getting many offers from stores for Macbook air but I don't know how to choose the newest model.
Is there any place where I can check based on the model num (e.g., MD711B)
I have tried on Apple website to see what is their latest version is but couldn't find

Comment: did you try google?  I typed just "MD711B vs MD711LLA" (without the quotes and without even the word Apple) and learned a lot really fast.

Comment: Yes. tried many times and each reference has different view. I am looking for something official to refer to the latest version.

Comment: What do you really learned? Did you read my question clearly? I am not referring to the sample versions I mentioned. what if I don't know what the current version is?

Comment: It's not hard to figure out, if you had done any research at all you can convulsively prove which of those two is the newer model and what the differences are.  What did you find in your research?  Most would down vote, I pass on that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Mac App Store and download Mactracker. It has a database of pretty much every Apple product ever made, its history and full specifications.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Many thanks.